# How can I access the property name's value in select box by clicking select option?

Tags: javascript

I want to access the name property and its value. When I click select tag. Here is the sample code

```
<select name="abc" id="input-abc"  onChange={(e)=>handleSelectButton(e)}>
  <option value="green" name="apple" >Apple</option>
  <option value="yellow" name="banana" >Banana</option>
</select>

function handleSelectButton(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }
```

If I will select Apple then the name is apple should come.
I can access only value but how to access the name property value. I have tried with `e.target.getAttribute("name")`.

Comment: just to clarify you want to get the name which is "apple" and its value which is Apple

Comment: `const selected = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex]` and do stuff with that.

Comment: Yes You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function handleSelectButton(e) {
  console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

```html
<select name="abc" id="input-abc" onChange="handleSelectButton(event)">
  <option value="green" name="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="yellow" name="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getAttribute() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].getAttribute("name");
  var y = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[1].getAttribute("name");

  console.log(x); // [0] is the first option tag
  console.log(y); // [1] is the second option tag
}

getAttribute()
```

```html
<select name="abc" id="input-abc" onChange={(e)=>handleSelectButton(e)}>
  <option value="green" name="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="yellow" name="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```